# Android theme declaration

Tags: android, themes, styles, parent, declaration

I have a problem. I created new app and publish it to market, but most part of users get ANR with

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
>   ... 39 more
>   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010019 a=-1}
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1699)
>   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
>   at android.view.View.(View.java:1998)
>   at android.view.View.(View.java:1946)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:304)
>   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:173)
>   ... 42 more

In my app I have a two themes that declared in themes.xml. I think I have a mistake in theme declaration. How properly define themes in styles? What difference between

```
 <style name="DarkTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

and

```
<style name="DarkTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

That theme declaration is correct. The @android tells your software to look inside the Android package for resources. :style means that inside the android package it should look at the styles of that package for the style named after the /.

Comment: ok. But what about <style name="DarkTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"> why this declaration mentioned in docs? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something similar to the first way of defining the theme parent, i.e.:

```
<style name="DarkTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

It works just fine for me. Perhaps try only using that. I've tried both ways and they seemed to work though.

Comment: thanks for reply, I also tried use both and both works fine, but I can't undrstand what is wrong with my app.

Comment: Well, the LogCat report should help you track down where the error occurs. Whatever you're doing in the line of code is probably wrong.

Comment: You can see a part of stacktrace in code above. But I cant determine the reason of mistake.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the complete report - is it?

Comment: I think I see something. Could you post the contents of your manifest.xml file?

Comment: Hmm, weird. That's not what I expected.

Comment: It seems I found the problem Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010019 a=-1} This value is a color not drawable. I deleted this value from styles but another same error appears. At this time android:src="?logo" for ImageView. In styles I have <item name="logo">@drawable/my_shows_logo_dark</item> Why this drawable is wrong? How I can properly set ImageView content via styles?